# length between 2 values

Tags: r, vector

In R, what is the most efficient way to count the length between 2 values. for example, i have vector x , which are all randomly choose from 1 to 100, how can i find out the length between the first"2" and first"40", 
x=(1,2,**3,4,5,6,7**,40,1,2,**3,21,4,1,23,4**,43,23,4,12,3,43,5,36,3,45,12,31,3,4,23,41,23,5,53,45,3,7,6,36)
for this vector, the answer should be 5 and 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure  I have understood exactly what you want, but here is an approach

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,40,1,2,3,21,4,1,23,4,43,23,4,12,3,43,5,36,3,45,12,31,3,4,23,41,23,5,53,45,3,7,6,36)

first2 <- which(x==2)[1]
first40 <- which(x>=40)[1]

first40 - first2 - 1
> 5

sec2 <- which(x==2)[2]
sec40 <- which(x>=40)[2]

sec40 - sec2 - 1
> 6
```

Comment: Not needed here, I ll correct it. Read this  http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/base/html/which.html